# FROMURI not working on localhost

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have a simple web api 2 controller that looks something like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("~/My/Stuff")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<MyStuff>))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAsync([FromUri]FilterRequest request)
    {
        var filter = request == null ? null : new Filter(request.Take, request.Skip);

        return Ok(await _service.GetAsync(filter).ConfigureAwait(false));
    }
```

My FilterRequest object is a simple DTO and looks like:

```
public class FilterRequest
{
    public int Take { get; set; }

    public int Skip { get; set; }
}
```

This then allows the call to be made like so:

http://localhost/My/Stuff?Take=5&Skip=10

My problem is, that this does not work locally.  On all other environments it works fine and it also works fine on other dev machines. But on my machine the request object comes through as null every time. Is there a setting, maybe in IIS or on my machine that will fix this?

Comment: There is no problem with the code. I think you should look at the differences between the machines. Are you using another OS, bit version, locale setting, IIS version? What version of Visual Studio (including updates) are you using? Are you using the same web.config? Do you also have this problem if you use a copy of the published website?

Comment: I tend to agree, code either works or doesn't - so changes environmentally must be external. Just did a quick comparison, we are on similar 64bit machines running win10, VS 2015 update 3 and use IIS express, so it's doesn't seem to be obvious.

Interestingly, when I inspect the request object while debugging, the query string is empty, which suggests why the filter object is null.But I'm not sure what is causing that.

Comment: Can you add a sample project that reproduces the problem on GitHub and post a link here?

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling it like this:

http://localhost/My/Stuff?request.Take=5&request.Skip=10

Here is an example:

http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/api/FromUri/Test1_WithFromUri?v.id=1&v.name=2

And the code behind that is here:

https://github.com/heldersepu/SwashbuckleTest/blob/master/Swagger_Test/Controllers/FromUriController.cs#L10

Comment: I get the same results if I try: http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/api/FromUri/Test1_WithFromUri?id=1&name=2